# What is the interface of this DVD/CD re-writable drive?

Tags: usb, adapter, optical-drive, cd-drive

I have removed a DVD/CD re-writable drive from Acer Aspire 5000 laptop. I want to make it an external one by connecting to [Sabrent USB 3.0 TO SATA/IDE 2.5/3.5/5.25-INCH Hard Drive Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DQJME7Y). 
But the converter doesn't seem to have an interface that can match the drive.

What is the interface of the drive? According to [a service manual](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/notebook/acer/acer_aspire_3000,_3500,_5000_series_service_guide.pdf) for several models of Acer laptops including Aspire 5000, is the interface enhanced IDE (ATAPI)?

What kind of converter do I need to make the drive into an external one?

The DVD/CD drive:

[image]

[image]

Mismatch between the converter and the drive:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Its called a Slim (Slimline) ATAPI

[image]

[Source](http://www.laptopparts101.com/cd-dvd-optical-drive/)

They make adapters that go to IDE, I have one. [There may be other adapter types](http://www.addonics.com/products/adsssau2.php). Addonics are high quality adapters. But these are for internal mounting in a desktop.

.

The white connector is the old floppy drive power cable, this is how it gets power for the drive

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is it correct that the link to Aliexpress is for Slim SATA, not for my drive which is Slim ATAPI? (2) Which interface is popular now, Slim SATA, Slim ATAPI, or something else? (3) Do today's laptops' optical drives still use different interfaces than hard drives? (I wonder if my Sabrent usb-SATA/IDE converter still not works for optical drives)

Comment: Yeah, I cannot seem to find a usb adapter for atapi slim, only the ones for internal mounting in a pc, no usb enclosures either. Probably best to just buy a usb dvd drive.

Comment: All slim optical drives are now Sata interface, which is what the cable I linked to is for.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Can the Addonics ones for internal use in desktop be used externally between a DVD drive and a usb port in laptop? (2) Do today's laptops' optical drives still use different interfaces than hard drives? (I wonder if my Sabrent usb-SATA/IDE converter still not works for optical drives). (3) Is my DVD drive hard to reuse and resell today in US?

Comment: Addonics adapters need a source of 5v power, so external use is not practical. There is no value for those old atapi slim dvd drives

Comment: Thanks. (1) For those optical drives that are full sized rather than slim, are their interfaces the same as those for hard drives, i.e. SATA, and IDE?  (2) If yes, can my Sabrent USB-SATA/IDE converter work for full sized optical drives? Actually my Sabrent converter works for IDE/SATA hard drives that are both desktop-sized and laptop-sized.  Slim optical drives might have a different size from a laptop-sized hard drives? (3) For those full sized optical drives, which interface is most popular: SATA, IDE, or something else?

Comment: Slim ATAPI to SATA adaptors do exist, e.g. http://www.ioi.com.tw/products/proddetail.aspx?CatID=101&HostID=2032&ProdID=1010104 (random google - no affiliation or recommendation)

Comment: @abligh I know that and have that in my answer with links and pictures, but he is looking for one to use it via usb

Comment: @Moab presumably he can just attach a USB/SATA convertor to that ...

Comment: Search for "slimline IDE" on eBay, there are a few adapters (e.g. [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/351673228747)), and you get more results than "slimline ATAPI". But in many cases it is cheaper to just buy a new slimline sata drive.

Comment: @T... That drive is quite old, and probably close to worthless. The entire laptop it came from, if working, would probably resell for around the cost of a new USB DVD burner (which can be had for [$25-$30](http://www.newegg.com/External-CD-DVD-Blu-Ray-Drives/SubCategory/ID-420), will perform better and support more formats such as M-Disc).